# Tabbing Navigation not working in form

Tags: html, css

so I'm working on a project in which I have a form, with some stepper fields and text fields. The problem I'm having is that when I hit the tab button in one of the fields, the focus does not change to the next field. I've tried setting tab index for the fields, but this doesn't seem to help.

I have a feeling the problem is that each of the fields in the form are wrapped in some DIVs as follows:

```
<div class="form_class">
  <div class="field_class">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <div class="fg-line p-t-15">
        <input tabindex="0" class="form-control amount_field input-mask-amount" type="number" step="0.01">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so the tabbing can't find the next field in the DOM, but I don't know how to get around this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are all tabindexes "0"? Generally you use "0" to represent programatic tabbing.

Comment: I've tried setting them all to 0 and also tried setting them in order ie 1,2,3,4,5, but neither seemed to work.

Comment: Does the current input lose focus when you hit tab? If it does you are probably correct about the nesting. If not, something else maybe trapping the keyboard event.

Comment: It doesn't lose focus on tab presses, however if I click near the element and hit tab, it will focus on the field.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your comments, I'd number your tabindexes sequentially and add a keypress event handler. If the key is 'tab', get the current element (document.activeElement), get its tabindex, increment it, find the corresponding element with that new index value and focus it manually.